# How to execute <script> code in a javascript append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events, nextgen-gallery

I'm working with a plugin that is only Javascript. I need to have it dynamically create a DIV element with an advertisement in it.

I can't figure out why this doesn't work:

```
$(this).append('<div class="overlay-background">Advertisement

     <script type="text-javascript">

          GA_googleFillSlot("blog_landing_right_rectangle_300x250");

     </script>'
```

It results in the element created with "Hello World" but it does not execute the GA-googleFillSlot function.

Comment: Do you use this code in the HTML page? if so, closing </script> could be treated as the closing tag from your outermost </script>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

appending HTML into the DOM does not cause the browser to evaluate any script tags in said appended HTML.

If you really wanted to, you could evaluate the javascript by using `eval()`:

```
eval($(this).find("script").text());
```

Comment: This solution causes an unknown white screen error when placed with $(this).append. It produces no change when placed outside of it. I did not modify the code from how it appears above.

Comment: Looks like dozens of bad requests on pubads.g.doubleclick.net. It looks like I'm appending in a loop (NextGEN gallery carousel).

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question but I've had a similar problem today.
The solution was using [createContextualFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment).

My code looks something like this:

```
var tagString = '<script async type="text/javascript" src="path_to_script"></script>';

var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]);
var documentFragment = range.createContextualFragment(tagString);
document.body.appendChild(documentFragment);
```

Answer (score 5):

This code works in my browser.

```
$('body').append('<script>alert("test");<' + '/' + 'script>');
```

so it might be that `$(this)` is what is actually causing your problem.

Can you replace it with `'body'` and see if it works like that?

Comment: This works for me, if you break the `</script>` in the string `...</' + 'script>');`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the script into script, since I usually put 'em into files.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround in your case could be to append a fake image with an onload event:

```
<img src="blank.gif" onload="GA_googleFillSlot('blog_landing_right_rectangle_300x250')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

since your are in javascript, you can append and then execute the code:

```
$(this).append('<div class="overlay-background">Advertisement</div>');

GA_googleFillSlot("blog_landing_right_rectangle_300x250");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
s = '<' + 'script type="text-javascript">' +
    'GA_googleFillSlot("blog_landing_right_rectangle_300x250");' +
    '<' + '/' + 'script>';
$(this).append(s);
```

UPD: alas, this won't work, please use wless1's solution instead

Comment: This won't help as the script won't run anyway.