# jQuery append another script to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html

i have a ad code like this:

```
       <script async src="//"></script>
         <!-- gdfdfhffdfdfdfk -->
         <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:125px;height:125px"
         data-ad-client="ssfdsfsdfds"
         data-ad-slot="445454454544454545445"></ins>
       <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
       </script>
```

and i have this div:

```
       <div id="asd"></div>
```

i want to append above ad script into #asd using jQuery append function.
i tried this:

```
var adcode = "above script"
$( "#asd" ).append(adcode);
```

but not working. please help me... Thanks

Comment: looks good to me. Are you sure you're calling jquery library?

Comment: Do you get an error, or does it just not work?

Comment: yes.. other jquery functions working properly...

Comment: I agree, looks like it should be working fine. So, is the ad code somehow not being inserted into the div or is the ad code itself not working?

Comment: no error... just not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269587/how-to-execute-script-code-in-a-javascript-append

Comment: Precisely what I was thinking, @paka. the code in the HTML you're appending won't be run unless you make it so either by calling `eval()` on it or putting it in a function you can call after you append it

Comment: @RogerMo ad code not being inserted...

Comment: @paka in your link, the answer is: "Script tags appended to the DOM are **not** evaluated." - Is that really true? When I try ``var s = $('<script type="text/javascript"> alert("he");</script>');
$('body').append(s);`` in Opera 12.16, Chrome, IE10, it always alerts "he"...

Answer (score 0):

Is #asd actually in the DOM at this point?  Try console.log($('#asd')) at the same point where your append code is and see if it is actually in the DOM.

You'll probably also need to do this on document ready like so:

```
$(function() {
    var adcode = "above script"
    $( "#asd" ).append(adcode);
});
```