# Reloading a div tag via jquery does not execute the script inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I have a smarty tpl like below with a script inside a div tag.

**smarty1.tpl**

```
...
<div id="div1">
...
<script>
Alert('script is executing');
...
</script>
</div>
...
```

I have **smarty2.tpl** file like below.

**smarty2.tpl**

```
...
<select id="choose">
  <option value="0">{$something1}</option>
  <option value="1">{$something2}</option>
  ...
</select>
{include file='smarty1.tpl'}
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#choose').change(function(event) {
  $("#div1").load(location.href + " #div1");}); 
</script>
```

when i load or reload the page (containing smarty2.tpl), it successfuly loads div tag, then run the script inside it and i see alert message.

When i change select box in smarty2.tpl, then jquery raises and it refreshes div tag successfully, but the script inside it, does not run and i can't see alert message.

How can i force the script to run in this case?
(EDIT: I don't think it is javascript append issue)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute <script> code in a javascript append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269587/how-to-execute-script-code-in-a-javascript-append)

Comment: You should not make your code like this. Putting a script tag inside an element is bad design. The convention says you should put all script at the end of your document. If you want to execute this script every time you change the select, wrap it in a function and put it at the end of your page. Then run this function when you change the select.

Comment: I tried to summarize my problem.Actually,the script should run only inside div tag.

Comment: Why exactly you need the script to run inside the div tag?

Comment: Actually, it is part of a form  with input tags and it should be run only if specific input field changes.

Comment: Yeah but you don't need the script tag to be inside that div for that to happen.

Comment: You do not have to load same script again, once you bind events, those are already set.