# How to make Google Analytics/Pixel scripts fire only on button-click event

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, google-analytics, header

hope i'll do good enough of a job in describing my challenge here..

## in short: How do i make Google Analytics && Facebook pixel scripts fire only when button is clicked and ***NOT*** on page load.

**in "longer"**: I have an iFrame that loads inside a different page; both pages share the same domain.
The requirement is for the iframe to be pre-loaded even if the visitor hasn't reached it yet, this scenario causes the GA & FB Pixel to send bias/false data as many times these iframes are never actually been viewed by the visitors.

as both pages have google analytics & facebook pixel implemented in their 'header' tag, i want these scripts to fire **only** when the visitor clicks a button located under the iframe area, this way avoiding false data back to google/pixel.

Im a beginner js coder and i have no idea how to do this.. can someone please help and/or share a tip or two on how to go about this.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232380/2083877

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Universal Analytics snippet, you may not enter the `ga('send', 'pageview');` command on loading and do so by clicking on the button. In this way the library is loaded and the pageview is not sent when the page is loaded.

If you use Google Tag Manager you can solve it easily because you can insert scripts in tags and activate them only when the user clicks on the button.

Another way could be define your scripts as text/plain, then when user click on button you can convert blocks from text/plain to text/javascript and execute it.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer! as there are potentially many snippets (GA, Pixel, hotjar, etc.) i want somehow to wrap all 3rd party snippets in some container and for that container to run only when the user clicks the button. 
Do you have an idea on ow can i wrap all these scripts and run them by click?

Comment: I added a kind of solution to my answer.

Comment: i see what you mean, but i dont want to rely on other 3rd party solutions for this, and develop my own solution for this scenario (also, i may want to wrap GTM inside this container as well). what are the chances that you can point me on how to go about it?

Comment: I added another suggestion.. the last one I have :)

Comment: @MichelePisani I converted blocks from text/plain to text/javascript, but it does not execute. How do i execute it?