# Can scripts and html be inserted with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I am getting one document from api response which contains html like this

I am inserting this document as innerHTML inside one page It is rendering properly but script is not executing.Please help me with this.How to set html so that script inside that also execute.

I tried to use set page as innerHTML

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>This is my Name</div>
            <div>This is something else</div>
        </div>
        <script src="demo_script_src.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Quite a lot of examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+page+with+script+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232380

Answer (score 0):

Replace response with your html code, and `targetElement`

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html');

var scriptTags = parsedHtml.querySelectorAll('script');

for (var i = 0; i < scriptTags.length; i++) {    
    var newScriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    newScriptTag.textContent = scriptTag.textContent;
    
    document.head.appendChild(newScriptTag);
}

var targetElement=...;
targetElement.append(...parsedHtml.documentElement.childNodes);
```

Comment: this is not a  answer to quetion

Comment: @XMehdi01 why is it not an answer? It does exactly what OP is asking

Comment: because don't using `innerHTML`

Comment: `How to set html so that script inside that also execute.` - OP does not ask to ONLY ALLOW innerHTML

Comment: Otherwise the answer is just "NO"

Comment: @mplungjan You are right

Comment: that's the solution that i know, hopping someone else gonna respond, and sorry if i didn't answer to your problem correctly

Comment: This solution is not working for my problem.